# JQUERY: Открыть выборочное изображение из галереи swipebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Есть проблема: есть галерея изображений на iPad - открывается через swipebox (http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/)

Ссылка на сам сайт - goo.gl/Ia5Gmg

Нужно сделать, чтобы озображение нужное я мог открыть по клику на ссылку. Тоесть кликая на ссылку в тексте - я могу открыть нужное мне изображение из галереи swipebox. Кто-то сталкивался с таким?

```
$('.text-block a').bind('click',function(e){
    var Link = $(this).attr('href');
    Link = Link.replace('#image','');
    myVariable = Link;
    if(Link!=undefined)
    {
        var CurrImg = $('.gallery-block').find('a')[Link];
        console.log($(CurrImg));
        $(CurrImg).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Есть такой код, однако триггер click не отрабатывает открытие изображения

Answer (score 0):

Так можно попробовать.

```
var x = 100; // в переменную x нужно указать общее количество изображений в sandbox
for (var i = 1; var i <= x; i++) {
  $('text-block a:nth-child('+ i +')').click(function(){
   $('.gallery-block div a:nth-child('+ i +')').click();
  });
}
```